# initialize UITableViewController with [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

As I understand this correctly form the Apple Api, when initializing a UITableViewController with the initWithStyle method, it should return me a reference to an UITableView in self.tableView. Which would make sense as you cannot change the style of a tableView once initialized.

But in my case this does not happen.

```
- (id)initWithSomeData:(SomeData *)someData {
    self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    if (self) {
    }
    NSLog(@"self? %@ tableView? %@", self, self.tableView);
    return self;
}
```

This display's a object ID for self, but self.tableView is null.
Am I doing something wrong?
I'm not using interface builder!

**Answer**:
Jan was actually right, I found out that the initialization process of a UITableViewController somewhat differs from a normal UIViewController.

My understanding was that at creation one of the init methods was called and would be completed before any other methods (loadView, viewDidLoad) we're called. This is correct for a UIViewController, but not for a UITableViewController.

The UITableViewController initWithStyle initializer actually calls loadView and viewDidLoad as part of it initialization process. The property of self.tableView is being set in loadView, but not if you override loadView, which I had done and hence, self.tableView was not being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tableView` object is probably created at a later point. Try to override:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad;
```

`self.tableView` should point to a valid objects at that point.

Comment: That was an good idee Jan, unfortunately no, the line NSLog(@"tableView? %@", self.tableView); Causes my app to crash when placed as the first line in LoadView. And also returns null when placed in viewDidLoad

Comment: That is weird, there must be an error somewhere else, can you post the whole class?

Comment: I actually found out the problem, wanted to post it as an answer to my own question but thats not allowed within 24h for a new user... strange.

Comment: Okay, though as a generel rule: If you override loadView or viewDidLoad, you should always call [super loadView] and [super viewDidLoad] as part of your overidden method.

Comment: That is true for viewDidLoad but not for loadView. [Apple API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/loadView). <quote>If you override this method in order to create your views manually, you should do so and assign the root view of your hierarchy to the view property. (The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object.) **Your custom implementation of this method should not call super**.</quote>