# how to use UITableViewStyleGrouped at the initialization?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

i found this link : [initialize UITableViewController with [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5620990/initialize-uitableviewcontroller-with-super-initwithstyleuitableviewstylegroupe)

but i don't understand the way to initialize the tableView as "grouped" inside the controller class?

> self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];

Could you help me?

Thanks a  lot

Paul

Comment: Might be helpful if you could explain where you want to change it. Do you have the table view in interface builder? You can change the style there or you can change it if you create the controller in code.

Comment: let's say you create a new project, a "navigation-based" controller, how can you directly write in the code the "grouped" style? if i create a tableview from another controller, i can put this initWithStyle:UITable... (my 1st post) but from the controller itself, the one created automatically by xcode, i dont see how to do it from the code.

Comment: The easiest way is to change the TableView in Interface Builder to Grouped style in the Attribute Inspector. To do this in code you would need to change the way the UITableViewControler is created. You would not do it through the xib, but in code in the AppDelegate. You could also change the code to a UIViewController and implement the table view delegates and change things yourself.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot scott, just by curiosity, in the appDelegate, you would add another method? how would you do this? (in theory) Thanks again edit : also, can you put an answer? i will check it as the solution

Comment: If you want to change this to be just in code, I would remove the nib that is loaded for the navigation conroller and create it in code in the app delegate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to change the TableView in Interface Builder to Grouped style in the Attribute Inspector. To do this in code you would need to change the way the UITableViewControler is created. You would not do it through the xib, but in code in the AppDelegate. You could also change the code to a UIViewController and implement the table view delegates and change things yourself.

Answer (score 3):

```
[self.tableView initWithFrame:self.view.frame style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but assuming you have a UITableViewController called myTableVC that is created via code (with no xib) and you want the table to display with a grouped style, you could do so by calling the view controller as follows:

```
MyTableViewController *myTableVC= [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
[self presentModalViewController:myTableVC animated:YES];
[myTableVC release];
```

Similarly, if you wanted a plain tableviewcontroller style, you could do so by:

```
    MyTableViewController *myTableVC= [[MyTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
```